# What is the meaning of 'ln -sT' in Linux?

Tags: symlink, ln

To be more precise: I know what the `-s` options stands for - I use it daily. But I saw someone in a tutorial, who was moving the document root of his website from `/var/www/html/project` to `~/www/project` to increase security (he later on changed the rights and so on, but's that not significant in this context). Then he created the following symlink:

```
ln -sT ~/www/project /var/www/html/project
```

I was wondering what the `-T` is for, because normally I would have just used `-s`. From the man page I get the following sparse information regarding the `-T` option:

```
-T, --no-target-directory
     treat LINK_NAME as a normal file always
```

I don't really understand what this is for. Why should I use `-T` in conjunction with `-s` when creating a symlink? Is there any great benefit from doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ln`’s synopsis is as follows:

```
ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

Without `-T`, if `LINK_NAME` already exists and is a directory (or symlink verified to eventually resolve to a directory), the first and third forms are ambiguous, and `ln` chooses the third form: it creates the link *inside* the directory. Thus

```
ln -s ~/www/project /var/www/html/project
```

will create a link named `project` inside `/var/www/html/project` if the latter already exists.

`-T` removes the ambiguity, and forces `ln` to consider the first form only: if the link doesn’t exist, the link is created as named; if there is already a file or directory with the given `LINK_NAME`, `ln` fails with an error (unless `-f` is specified too).

So

```
ln -sT ~/www/project /var/www/html/project
```

guarantees that you end up either with a link `/var/www/html/project` pointing to `~/www/project`, or with an error message (and non-zero exit code).

Comment: Note that `cp` and `mv` have similar ambiguities when then can be either move/copy **to** or **into** depending on the  perceived nature of the target or the number of arguments. GNU added `-T` for those as well.

Comment: For `mv`: [How to decide that mv moves into a directory rather than replacing directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/61402)

Answer (score 2):

It makes sure your path (in your example `/var/www/html/project`) is the final path, so the link will 100% be `/var/www/html/project` and not `/var/www/html/project/**project**` if `/var/www/html/project` exists...

Because this might be confusing, showing the example of difference

Setup:
`cd /tmp`;
`mkdir /tmp/aa`;
`mkdir /tmp/bb`;

`ln -s /tmp/aa /tmp/bb` will result in new symlink `/tmp/bb/aa -> /tmp/aa`

whereas

`ln -sT  /tmp/aa /tmp/bb` will result in `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/tmp/bb': File exists`

the `-s` parameter has nothing to do with it. It is (as usual) explained in thedocs: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Target-directory.html